# Angular Material Navbar Not Working

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

So all of my other angular material related items are functioning properly. However, the Nav bar is refusing to load properly. Here's my code.

```
<md-nav-bar>
<md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/" name="page3">Home</md-nav-item>
<md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/about" name="page3">About</md-nav-item>
</md-nav-bar>
```

Yet the output is as though it were just plain text. I've tested it on the example codepen for the element and it works properly. I've tropple checked my code and can fuind no obvious issues.

Any and all help is welcome.

Comment: are you loading it in a `md-content` ?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. The issue was that the bower package was an outdated version. Simply including the CDN code fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use md-tabs instead gives the same effect when used with ui-router......
i tried it for hours and got nothing on md-menu and md-nav-bar both ,,,,,, i think the above solution for including the cdn libraries is good .... but i recommend md-tabs for good results